Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'Element' while variable are NodeList
trying to select all radio input and their checked status  using below code
  const radioInput = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");
  radioInput.forEach((r) => (r.checked = r.defaultValue === 'whatever'));

this is working in javascript but now trying to convert into typsscript and now it
gives below typing error inside forEach()

Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'Element'.

also when we hover on radioInput variable,  its display NodeList<Element>
the tsconfig.json have below entry
"lib": [
      "es2022",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable"
    ],


How can we fix this?
Already checked similar questions, most of answer are React related while my code is written in typescript only (.ts, not .tsx)
Working Demo

To access checked you need to consider element as HTMLInputElement instead of HTMLElement, i.e. (r: HTMLInputElement)
Here is the example from your demo:
// Import stylesheets
import './style.css';

// Write TypeScript code!

const radioInput = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
radioInput.forEach((r: HTMLInputElement) => (r.checked = r.defaultValue === 'X'));

const enum Shape {
  Circle,
  Square,
}

console.log(Shape['1']);


it works, Thanks but follow up question is that why do we have to set explicit typing  here?

When you query using methods like document.getElementById or querySelector, the return type is HTMLElement because the method doesn't know what specific type of element, as not all elements have same properties like:

HTMLInputElement has properties like value, checked, type, etc.
HTMLButtonElement has properties like disabled, form, etc.

Explicit typing is necessary to leverage TypeScript's type system effectively, ensuring that only valid properties and methods are accessed for a given element. This prevents potential runtime errors and makes the code more robust and maintainable.

fair. But when we write ahead to document.querySelectorAll(...) as HTMLInputElement[] ut doesnt work, although it should work. isn't it?

reason being document.querySelectorAll(...) returns all elements not just Input but later you can as you might filtered input element for your requirement.
